# How in PHP to add values from one array to another when their key value pairs match?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here are my two arrays:

```
$array1 =( [0] => Array ( [row_id] => 237 [comment] => 'hello0' )
           [1] => Array ( [row_id] => 5 [comment] => 'hello1' ) 
           [2] => Array ( [row_id] => 6 [comment] => 'hello2' ) );

$array2= ( [0] => Array ( [row_id] => 5 [vote] => 1 ) 
           [1] => Array ( [row_id] => 7 [vote] => 1 ) 
           [2] => Array ( [row_id] => 237 [vote] => 0 ) );
```

I'd like to match `$array1` and `$array2` on `[row_id]` and add `$array2`'s
 `[vote]` key/value pairs to $array1 where `$array1[row_id]=$array2[row_id]`

This is how I'd like the output to be:

```
$array1 =( [0] => Array ( [row_id] => 237 [comment] => 'hello0' [vote] => 0  )
           [1] => Array ( [row_id] => 5 [comment] => 'hello1' [vote] => 1 ) 
           [2] => Array ( [row_id] => 6 [comment] => 'hello2' [vote] => 1 ) );
```

I'm sure there are many ways to do this, so thoughts on the fastest computationally would also be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried using array_merge()? http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: How do you wan't to deal with the fact that you have duplicated `row_id`s? What if the values of `vote` for the duplicated rows were different? How would the result array look then?

Comment: hi DaveRandom, sorry that was a mistake. I'm correcting the question now...

Comment: hi jammypeach, so let me see it's just as simple as `array_merge($array1, $array2);`?

Comment: yep but I don't think it will give you exactly what you want - @RayCheng's answer looks more like it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foreach($array1 as $key1=>$value1)
{
  foreach($array2 as $key2=>$value2)
  {
     if($value1['row_id']==$value2['row_id'])
     {
         $value1['vote'] = $value2['vote'];
         $result[$key1][]=$value1;
     }
 }
}

$result is what you need!
```

Comment: hi Ray, yes this works great! is it the most performant (fastest computationally)?

Comment: if you like you can use for() instead of foreach();

Comment: hi Ray, actually i just realized that your method creates another array inside each of `$array1`'s arrays. Is there any way to do this by just adding the key value pair `[vote]=>x` and not nesting in a new array? here's what your foreach loop currently does: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [row_id] => 237 [comment] => hello0 [vote] => 0 ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [row_id] => 5 [comment] => hello1 [vote] => 1 ) ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [row_id] => 6 [comment] => hello2 [vote] => 1 ) ) )`

Comment: Currently, each array has an unwanted `[0] => Array` indexed array. Here's how I'd like it to look: `Array (( [0] => Array ( [row_id] => 237 [comment] => hello0 [vote] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [row_id] => 5 [comment] => hello1 [vote] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [row_id] => 6 [comment] => hello2 [vote] => 1 ) )`

Comment: i think you already fixed!if you want to learn loop in php you need do more exerise;its not hard!

Comment: hi ray, the answer below is not quite correct. this is still hard for me. would you mind showing me what the loop would look like if the row_id we're instead the keys for each array? Malovich says I would then only need 1 foreach loop. thanks

Comment: use this sql :select a.row_id,a.comment,b.vote from tableA as a left join tableB as b on a.row_id=b.row_id;

Comment: thanks Ray, my arrays were derived from queries like that, I was instead looking for a PHP solution to JOIN tables a and b on a.row_id=b.row_id

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($array1 as $key1=>$value1)
{
    foreach($array2 as $key2=>$value2)
   {
       if($value1['row_id']==$value2['row_id'])
       {
           if ($value2['vote']) {
               $result[$key1]['vote']=$value2['vote']; // You're assigning the vote value to a new index of 'vote' on the original array.
           } else {
               $result[$key1]['vote'] = 'no vote';
           }
       }
   }
}
```

This is the change that is needed in Ray Cheng's answer.

EDIT'd

EDIT'd again:

When pulling data from a database, you can definitely get the records as an array (look it up, its as old as the hills, the code is out there). The next step is reorganizing the array into the preferred format. `FOREACH` is ideal for this.

```
// $array1 brought in from some other process
$arrayStorage = array();
foreach ($array1 as $row){ 
    $arrayStorage[$row['row_id']] = array('votes'=>$row['votes'], 'comment'=>$row['comment']);
}
```

When you want to put it back into the database, reverse it, making sure you pull the keys out again.

```
foreach ($arrayStorage as $row_id=>$row_data){ ...
```

EDIT the LAST:

Assuming that both respective databases have been pulled for data into the OP's format...

```
foreach ($array1 as $row){ 
    $arrayStorage[$row['row_id']]['comment'] = $row['comment'];
}

foreach ($array2 as $row){ 
    $arrayStorage[$row['row_id']]['votes'] = $row['votes'];
}
$array1 = $arrayStorage;

// You are going through $array1 and $array2 and creating a placeholder that is built with the $row_id as an associated structure with a comment and vote for each $row_id. This is your final desired array.
```

Comment: thanks Malovich, i'm noticing your or Ray Cheng's code starts to break down if `$array1` and `$array2` don't contain the same number of arrays or if they don't perfectly match in `row_id` values. I'd like the output to contain as many arrays as are present in `$array1` and just to assign a value of `"no vote"` if `$value1['row_id']!=$value2['row_id']`. Could you help edit your code to do that? thanks!

Comment: The number of array's within each array shouldn't matter; you're iterating through both of them to make the comparison on the `$row_id`. Mind, it would have been superior to simply build both arrays with the `$row_id` as the key to the data. ....also, your suggestion would *overwrite every other array except the one you are handling*!

Comment: thanks Malkovich, I would like to build the arrays with the `$row_id `as the key to the data if that is easier, I just don't know how to do that either. My output is coming from a MySQL database as a numeric array. I'm using codeigniter for the php and the `result_array()` function http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html. Would you mind sharing the php code to build the array with `$row_id` as the key?

Comment: thanks awesome! one last thing i noticed: If you change the `row_id` value for `$array2`, e.g., from `row_id=6` to `row_id=7`, then the `$result` array lacks the 3rd key/value vote pair for `row_id=6`. Is there one more code modification you could do to assign a `"no vote"` value in cases where the two arrays, `$array1` and `$array2`, don't perfect match in terms of `row_id's`? Also, you mentioned it but can you explain why having the `row_id` be key is "superior" to how it currently is?

Comment: First, why are you changing the keys of the second array? Of course it will be missing data if you do that; also, if you do so, that's where you would need the logic to pull the data out of the first array to get the second new array key to match.

Comment: I'm changing the keys of the second array because this is more reflective of what my database queries actually give back. Fixing my MySQL queries seemed harder than just trying to deal with the two arrays in PHP. So considering this, can we try again working from your `$arrayStorage = array();` code where `$array1` gets converted to `$arrayStorage` with key `$row_id`?

Comment: It takes very little to do so; the `$row` array was based on `$array1`'s structure. Where does `$array2` come from/how is it generated?

Comment: i have comments in one DB table and votes in a separate table. I'd like to match the two arrays (2 separate mysql queries) using PHP and not a `JOIN` on `row_id` because that query would be way too complicated. Sorry about this, clearly arrays are clearly not my expertise. thank you for your continued help!

Comment: The beauty of the system I recommend is that if both arrays are formatted with the keys being the `$row_id`, you simply then have a single `foreach` for the new `$array1` which populates `$array1[$key]['votes']` with the value of `$array2[$key]['votes']`. OTOH, the MySQL `JOIN` query wouldn't be that hard, I don't think.

Comment: thanks, i'm trying to figure out if the MySQL query is doable for me. It would involve a subquery which I'm also not familiar with. I'd like to accept your answer, you've been **very** helpful. Before you go, would you mind posting the code in your answer for the single `foreach` loop where both array keys are `$row_id`?