# In PHP, how do I add values together from 2 arrays where specific keys match?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I found this article ([How in PHP to add values from one array to another when their key value pairs match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399924/how-in-php-to-add-values-from-one-array-to-another-when-their-key-value-pairs-ma)) which explained a similar, but slightly different operation than what I'm trying to do.

Here are my two arrays:

```
$array1 =( 
    [0] => Array ( [count] => 2 [time] => 12 [location] => 1041)
    [1] => Array ( [count] => 5 [time] => 5 [location] => 1700)
    [2] => Array ( [count] => 3 [time] => 10 [location] => 1500));

$array2 =( 
    [0] => Array ( [count] => 1 [time] => 12 [location] => 1041)
    [1] => Array ( [count] => 5 [time] => 5 [location] => 1700)
    [2] => Array ( [count] => 6 [time] => 10 [location] => 1500));
```

I'd like to build a new array in which the `[count]` values from `$array1` and `$array2` are added together where the keys `[time]` and `[location]` from `$array1` and `$array2` match.

This is how I'd like the output to be:

```
$compositeArray =(
    [0] => Array ( [count] => 3 [time] => 12 [location] => 1041)
    [1] => Array ( [count] => 10 [time] => 5 [location] => 1700)
    [2] => Array ( [count] => 9 [time] => 10 [location] => 1500));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of doing this (***without nesting loops***) would be to iterate through `$array1`, check and see if the same key exists in `$array2` (assuming they are organized by order already) and creating a new array of the data after calculations take place.

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
{
    if( array_key_exists($key, $array2) && $value['time'] == $array2[$key]['time'] && $value['location'] == $array2[$key]['location'] )
    {
        $result[] = array(
            'count'    => $value['count'] + $array2[$key]['count'],
            'time'     => $value['time'],
            'location' => $value['location']
        );
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: This solution is perfect for my application, and the lack of nested loops helps for a beginner like me, thanks.

Comment: @diverdan no problem, if this is the answer go ahead and select it so others are aware.

Answer (score 0):

Building off the accepted answer to the question you linked to:

```
foreach($array1 as $key1=>$value1)
{
  foreach($array2 as $key2=>$value2)
  {
    if($value1['time']==$value2['time'] && $value1['location']==$value2['location'])
    {
      $value1['count'] += $value2['count'];
      $result[$key1][]=$value1;
    }
  }
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this:

$result = array();
foreach($array1 as $key1=>$value1)
{
    foreach($array2 as $key2=>$value2)
  {
        if($value1['time']==$value2['time'] && $value1['location']==$value2['location'])
     {
         $value['count'] = $value1['count']+$value2['count'];
         $result[] = array("count"=>$value['count'],"time"=>$value1['time'],"location"=>$value1['location']);
     }
 }
}
var_dump($result);
```

[working demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/rz36-kd18)